# How to pass data from Node.js to embedded Javascript in EJS Template?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Trying to pass data fetched from our SQL server to an EJS template with some embedded Javascript. Here are some snippets of my code to show you what I am trying to do.

**Route file**

```
    const data = await sqlCalls.getMenuAccess(req.user.UserIdNo)
    const data2 = await sqlCalls.getAvailability();
    const menus = data.recordset
    const availability = data2.recordset
    res.render('portal-availability', 
        { 
            title: 'Availability', 
            name: req.user.FirstName, 
            menudata: menus, 
            availabilitydata: availability  // <--- This is the data that I want to use in my EJS template.
        });
});
```

**HTML Portion of my EJS template**

```
<section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="block-header">
                <h2>AVAILABILITY</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="grid"></div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

**Javascript in my EJS template**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: availability,     // <---- This is where I am trying to use availability to bind to my grid.
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                ItemIdNo: { type: "number" },
                                cultivardescription: { type: "string" },
                                containerdescription: { type: "string" },
                                week0: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Jim